# /dev/sda1: clean, 220240/30269440 file, 2971359/121076736 blocks

Tags: 16.04

ubuntu 16.04 LTS how can i resolve this issue it comes when boot and shutdown and also in that case my ubuntu is not downloading it have dependence error sudo apt-get update so and soo are not working properly by this problem please anyone can help me

```
/dev/sda1: clean, 220240/30269440 file, 2971359/121076736 blocks
```

Comment: That `/dev/sda1: ...` is **not** an error. It's just a message saying that your hard drive isn't corrupted - something which Ubuntu checks every boot.

Comment: So how to resolve the problem

Comment: It's not a problem as @BharadwajRaju said. If you are asking about dependencies error then modify your question.

Comment: everyone is right, I am just commenting to say 'blocks' here are bits of data being checked/counted, it does **not** mean 'block' as in 'stop something from happening'. This message is **not** related to your issue with `sudo apt-get update` so you should edit your question to include the exact error message you get when you run that command

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Answer (score 4):

> Ubuntu versions 15.04 and newer perform a quick file system check on the root disk and report the result on the screen.
>
> The message
>   /dev/sda2: clean, 286631/6111232 files, 2586472/24413952 blocks
>   has the following meaning:
>
> The partition that was checked is "/dev/sda"
>   The file system is "clean", i.e. there are no inconsistencies
>   "286631/6111232 files": The file system has been created to allow a maximum of 6,111,232 files, and currently there are 286,631 files,
>   "2586472/24413952 blocks": The storage capacity of the file system is 24,413,952 blocks (probably 4096 bytes each), and 2,586,472 blocks currently are in use.
>
> This is an informational message confirming that the file system is ok. There is nothing that needs to be resolved or repaired.

See the link https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/293967. There you will find a more information.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with one of my Ubuntu partitions (I have two and a couple Mints). My production partition boots normally and lightning fast as it always has (originally a 10.04 Lucid). The one I'm in now does do that and it  s l o w s  down the boot time considerably. I guess the question is if it's possible to prevent the check happening -every- time you boot up... Both are upgraded to 16.04 LTS

Comment: This is not the solution. Just a copy paste of what the message board reply was. I am having the same issue now and I cannot do anything on the system.