# I fear that my hard drive may be about to break

Tags: boot, hard-drive

Whenever I boot my computer, there's almost always a brief interruption in the otherwise normal boot process. A black background with white text, with something along these lines showing:

`/dev/sda2 clean: <number>/<bigger number> blocks`

Or, perhaps even scarier:

`/dev/sda2 clean: <number>/<bigger number> blocks
<number>/<bigger number>
<number>/<bigger number>`

So on and so forth. My question is this: Is my hard drive about to die?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been answered here:

[/dev/sda1: clean, 220240/30269440 file, 2971359/121076736 blocks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774087/dev-sda1-clean-220240-30269440-file-2971359-121076736-blocks)

The top voted answer in that post explains it perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

As the linked answer states `fsck` should be run occasionally, but not *"almost always"* as in your case. To see how often it is run use:

```
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
$ sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sdc3
dumpe2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Filesystem volume name:   F9m_Linux
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          d02dc21d-dcb2-478e-9f7d-9a3331931de4
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              1921360
Block count:              7679931
Reserved block count:     383996
Free blocks:              4432862
Free inodes:              1339922
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      1022
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8176
Inode blocks per group:   511
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Sat Mar  5 10:58:45 2016
Last mount time:          Sun Nov 13 15:24:36 2016
Last write time:          Sun Nov 13 15:24:34 2016
Mount count:              300
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Sat Mar  5 10:58:45 2016
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          2530 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
First orphan inode:       791391
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      1c470968-41be-4895-ac56-52853ea75721
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Journal features:         journal_incompat_revoke
Journal size:             128M
Journal length:           32768
Journal sequence:         0x00357fcb
Journal start:            30244
```

But in your case replace `sdc3` in the example with `sda2`.

In this example `fsck` is run every single boot.

To change how often `fsck` is run on your disk use:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -c 50 -i 1m /dev/sda2
```

This sets the run frequency to every 50 boots or once a month.

Now you should see:

```
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@dell:~$ sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sdc3 | grep Next
dumpe2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@dell:~$ sudo tune2fs -c 50 -i 1m /dev/sdc3
tune2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Setting maximal mount count to 50
Setting interval between checks to 2592000 seconds
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@dell:~$ sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sdc3 | grep Next
dumpe2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Next check after:         Mon Apr  4 11:58:45 2016
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@dell:~$
```

Comment: I do not use an SSD, I use an HDD. However, the output of the first command is as follows: 

`dumpe2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Mount count:              81
Maximum mount count:      -1`

Comment: @Krieger I got my original information from a bad source and changed the answer. Hopefully it makes more sense now. Please let me know.

Comment: Perfect. Lengthy but well explained. This post should help people in the future. :)