# Can't login after installing graphics driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, login

After updating the bios and installing Ubuntu 16.04 I went to install the Nvidia 375 graphics driver for my Nvidia Geforce GTX 1080 graphics card. Everything appeared to install correctly so I went to restart the computer to complete installation.

On reaching the login screen I attempt to login but am displayed with this message:
"/dev/sda2: clean, 223731/20229632 files, 3079056/112906752 blocks"

The message appears for less than a second before I am returned to the login screen.

I found the following questions with the same issue:
[My Ubuntu is running fsck on every bootup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383114/my-ubuntu-is-running-fsck-on-every-bootup)
[/dev/sda1: clean, 220240/30269440 file, 2971359/121076736 blocks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774087/dev-sda1-clean-220240-30269440-file-2971359-121076736-blocks)
[Startup problem in 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761653/startup-problem-in-16-04-lts)

I failed to identify a conclusive solution regarding these problems however. I am probably just being dumb though. I am new to Ubuntu so please try to explain simply if possible. Thank you ^-^

Answer (score 0):

The message "/dev/sda2: clean, 223731/20229632 files, 3079056/112906752 blocks" is a good/normal message to see. It says that your file system check was good.

To solve the login problem, do the following...

- replace your_username, shown below, with your username

  1. boot the computer and observe the GRUB menu
  2. choose `advanced options`
  3. choose `root access`
  4. type `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`
  5. type `cd /home/your_username`
  6. type `sudo chown your_username:your_username .ICEauthority`
  7. type `sudo chown your_username:your_username .Xauthority`
  8. type `reboot`
  9. login like normal

If for some reason you still can't log in, you may have to fix a /tmp directory problem, or roll back your recent video driver installation.

Comment: hey heynnema i tried the steps you suggested but to no avail. Thank you for answering anyway. Can you recommend a good guide on fixing /tmp directory issues? I am reluctant to uninstall my graphics driver.

Comment: You might check http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop for other fixes for your problem, including the /tmp directory fix. The video driver that you installed could still be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So to anyone with this issue. I fixed it by pressing f2 on start up and going into uefi and bios. Then going to boot and changing the os option from windows to other.